# How to call PHP form using Ajax in Express/node.JS app

Tags: php, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to send a form using ajax PHP inside an Express app.
An Ajax file calls for the PHP validation once the send button is pressed.

At the moment I get back a 404 on my PHP file which is located in the Express public folder:

```
    ../php/contact.php
```

Folder structure in Express:

[image]

AJAX route:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "../php/contact.php");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {}
```

Is there a better way to do this or where should I locate my PHP file?

Many thanks

Comment: if your node server is not running on port 80 or 443 then you need to add the absolute url including the port on which php file is located

Comment: Hi, the app is running on a Heroku domain

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using PHP-express https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express
Also, it requires PHP to be installed on the local machine.
PHP folder needs to be located inside the views folder instead of public folder.

code in server.js:

```
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
binPath: 'php'
});

app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);
```